# Divergent sequences are members of a sigma algebra

Tags: measure-theory

I'm trying to show that if I have $g_{i}, g: (X, M) \rightarrow (\mathbb{R}, \mathbb{B}(\mathbb{R}))$ where $i \in \mathbb{N}$ then the following belongs to $M$.

$$\{x \in X: g_{i} \nrightarrow g(x)\} \in M$$

Notation:

- $M$ is a sigma-algebra
- $\mathbb{B}(\mathbb{R})$ denotes the Borel sigma algebra.

What I've tried:

So to be in the sigma algebra I need to show that it is closed under complements and closed under countable unions.

I'm guessing I can use the fact the functions are measureable in some way, but I'm not too sure how to proceed. Any hints?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\{x:g_n(x) \nrightarrow g(x)\}=\cup_{k=1}^{\infty} \cap_{n=1}^{\infty} \cup_{m=n}^{\infty} \{x:|g_m(x)-g(x)| >\frac 1 k\}$. [What this says is $(g_n(x))$ does not tend to $g(x)$ iff there exists $k$ such that $|g_m(x)-g(x)| >\frac 1 k$ for infinitely many $n$ which is true iff there exists $k$ such that for every $n$ there exits $m \geq n$ with  $|g_m(x)-g(x)| >\frac 1 k$].

$\{x:|g_m(x)-g(x)| >\frac  1k \}$ is the inverse image under the measurable function $g_m-g$ of $\{t: \in \mathbb  R: |t|>\frac 1 k\}$ and this last set is a Borel set.

Comment: That makes sense, I wouldn't have got the unions and intersections. So we can treat $\cup$ as "there exists" and $\cap$ as "for all"? Thanks.

Comment: @VBACODER Exactly! Union is the symbolic form of 'for some' or 'there exists' and intersection is the symbolic form of 'for all' or 'for every'.

Comment: Once you do a few of these, you will just look at something like $\{x \in X: g_{i} \nrightarrow g(x)\}$ and know it is in $M$.  You are just checking in your mind that the unions and intersections are countable because we are in the real numbers.  The important thing that Kavi did was to use $1/k$ and not $\epsilon > 0$ in there.